# Sales force chatter trigger

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-service-cloud

Iam getting my messages which i share in chatter to my followers on to their mobiles.My problem is all my followers are getting the  sms.But it should send sms to a particular follower which i specify  in chatter with
@ followername .Will @ woek in trigger if not how can i draw that functionality in trigger

Any Suggestions are apreciated.

Thanks&Regards
A.Anil kumar

Comment: This question probably needs an edit. I am not sure if you are referring to the standard Salesforce chatter app, or a custom functionality you've built for your org. Can you please clarity?

Comment: Iam working with standared chatter app only trying to write a trigger on chatter

Answer (score 0):

Currently the REST API is the only way to programmatically tag users in a post with the @ format. You can read more about it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_how_to.htm#cc_post_mentions).

Comment: Hi jonnybro Thanks for replying

Comment: Now i got that ..how to obtain a chatter free user also  swend an sms ...for that the application should also be present with them..but chatter free user have no such permissions to download app or share apps of system admin...how i can do this... waiting for your reply